# Supporting query on dynamic columns in elastic search

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I need to support query on dynamic (not predefined) tags in elastic search. Lets say I have a blog document and wanted to support query on different set of columns i.e. tagTypeA=valueX & tagTypeB=ValueY and these tagTypeX columns are not known beforehand. There will be only one value for each of these tags. The user will pass this additional data as Map String::String to my API (no strict model / structure). I also need to support aggregation queries on these tag columns.

I am thinking of three ways to support this feature.

1. Declare that I can support a maximum of N type of dynamic tags only per document (say 10) and create internal columns like Tag1,Tag2 ... Tag10. Now have a config to maintain the mapping of TagTypeA=Tag1, TagTypeB=Tag2 etc. In the code, iterate the input key value pair and generate ES search query dynamically by using key to columnName mapping.

Pros : Simple to implement

Cons : Overhead of maintaining the mapping. This has to modified every-time a new type of document/client is onboarded / new field has to be added for existing client.

2. Create a non-analyzed field in ES with array of strings. When storing the data, store in a concatenated format of key+"Delimiter"+value. So if the input map has TagTypeA=Good & TagTypeB=High, then this will be stored as ["TagTypeA-Good","TagTypeB-High"] in ES. When user queries, construct back the contacted strings and search them.

Pros : No code changes required to onboard new clients / to add or update new fields

Cons : First of all it doesn't sound clean. The key should not have Delimeter. Changing mapping at later point of time is very tedious as we have to change values of all existing string values.

3. Don't define any schema and let the json key - value pair of tags passthrough to elastic search PUT call. For any new keys which are not already present elastic search will automatically add it to the indices with default type inference (controlled using dynamic templates with restriction that all field names should start with a certain prefix).

Pros : No configuration or manual concatenation of input. Any addition of columns in handled transparently without any manual effort.

Cons : I am sure there would be some cons with this. But can't think of anything concrete. Please suggest? One con which I can think is, as the field names are left out wild, any one abusive client can bloat up the index which can potentially bring down whole cluster due to large number of fields, unless we have a workflow to manually register & approve these fields sotred in seperate DB. any other cons?

I am personally thinking on aligning to Option #3.

Can any one please share your views on above three approaches and if there is a better way to solve this.

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guts also tell me that option #3 is the most viable one. Using a dynamic template for configuring the potentially new tags coming in is the good approach.

Since those will always be tags named `TagTypeX`, it's easy to configure that dynamic template to always store `not_analyzed` value, there's no reason why this "may not always suit the requirements", a tag is a tag and there should not be different ways of searching them. If it was the case, you'd need another field type.

Personally, I don't see much cons to this approach. It's both flexible and evolutive and doesn't mess with the tag data solely based on purely technical reasons, like the other options.

Option 1 clearly adds too much overhead in case you have new tags and also limits the number of tags for no real reason (a technical reason is not a valid reason from the user's perspective).

Option 2 will be a hassle to maintain and as you rightly put it, is not clean.

There might be other options, but that depends on how you're building your queries (i.e. query DSL or simply a query string query in the URL), so I won't dive in there for now.

Comment: If I enforce that all Keys should start with TagType prefix, then yes dynamic template should suit the requirements. Seems the right way to have this prefix restriction if I go with #3 option

Comment: However I later realized one more con with #3, as the keys are now kept open wild in the world, if any client abuses by creating new keys everytime, then it will create lot of columns under one index and can potentially bring down the complete cluster due to one bad client. One way could be is to have a pre-registration of what are allowed fields per client and approve them. On every query check if the keys are present in this pre-registered list. This would prevent this issue, but needs a UI or workflow to be developed & monitored. What are your views on this? Any better way to this?

Comment: Bringing down a cluster by creating too many fields in an index... well you can go a long way before this happens. I've seen documents with several thousand fields and ES wouldn't budge. I wouldn't worry too much about this. In the end, you need to ask yourself whether it's in the client's interest to bring down the software he's using. Moreover, you could use the percolator to be alerted if too many tags are being created, but I doubt that it would ever happen.

Comment: My other idea would be a mix between option 2 and 3, i.e. have an array of `tags: [{name,value}]` so you'd only really create a single field and tags would be stuffed in that array. If you go that route, though, the array needs to be `nested`

Comment: Sounds interesting. However will there be any performance impact of it being a nested object compared to options #2 & #3? I am expecting high amount of queries on these tags. A typical document will have 3 to 4 tags and max possible would around 8-10.

Comment: I don't see any, but again I don't know how much data we're talking and how you've sized your hardware (SSD, RAM, CPU, etc), which are both important factors when talking performance. Best is to try it out on a test cluster and see how it's going.

Comment: Let say it can have 100 million records on rolling basis ( as we purge old records). Haven't thought through the hardware yet, but that should not be a big limitation. I was just asking performance relative to other options #3 & #4. Will try it out with sample test cluster.

Comment: One more point which I missed in stating the requirement was to be able to query for aggregations like count based on combination of tag columns. Not sure if this will impact the analysis of above 4 solutions?

Comment: Oh, then if we're talking aggregations, the mapping design is paramount, and option #3 (with or without the `nested` design I suggested) is clearly the one and only option you have if you want to produce meaningful aggregation data. I suggest you try that and then create more specific questions on more specific problems you will encounter, as this question is a pretty generic one, and as such, I would consider it answered.

Comment: Thanks Harish, appreciate! Eager to see your next questions ;)